# Has parrying changed in Dark Souls II since patch 1.04?

Tags: dark-souls-2

According to the [DSII wiki](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Parry+Frame+Data), as of Patch 1.04 Calibration 1.08, the various weapons have the following parry properties (graphic courtesy of *TheHolyChicken86*):

[image]

However, others have noted that this information might be out of date because of recent patches. In [this thread](http://fextralife.com/forums/t39643/fast-small-shield-vs-parry-small-shield-parry-frames/), users noted that the graphic implies that the target shield (type: parry small shield) has the same parry setup time as the watcher's shield (type: fast small shield) which doesn't seem to be the case. In fact, parry small shields in general appear to have longer setup time.

Has parrying been affected by recent patches?

Comment: I'm not sure how this is off-topic: It's asking about parry information.

Comment: @TwilightSparkle You're not asking for the information, really - as the question is phrased, you are asking "how currently accurate is this website", not for the actual current data.

Comment: I have changed it as requested.

Comment: Your original question asked about a website's accuracy; that's not a very useful question, as answers to it are going to be be outdated rather quickly.  But by focusing on the issue you're asking about, that's something in-game we can test, and verify.  It's much more useful, and lasts longer.

Comment: Fair enough, I see your point.